# Extending tags feature

Tags: php, oop, redbean

How would you extend the "Tags" feature of RedBean PHP to store more information than the title ? I would like to add `usage` or `creation_date` column, for instance.

I can see in the library code source that one can `dispense()` a tag (https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/RedBeanPHP4_1_X/RedBeanPHP/TagManager.php#L215)

So, Tags are really a Bean like any other bean, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Yes.

After some testing, it turned out that the tag feature exposed in RedBeanPhp can be used like any other bean.